# django Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have made a virtual environment and installed following:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

and my setting is :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
    'USER': 'DB_USER',
    'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'localhost', 
    'PORT': '3306',

}
```

}

and when I do `manage.py syncdb` it gives the error saying `2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`

I dont know whats wrong in here... 
I searched for it... Mostly I found if I use virtualenvironment then the above setting is enough... Whats wrong in here ???

Comment: Are you sure that mysql is running? Also, are you sure the sock is located at /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock. Try running `service mysqld restart` in your console.

Comment: I was about to ask if mysql was running, but the code defines a port, which means Django shouldn't be looking at the socket file at all...

Comment: it gives the error mysqld: unrecognized service when I do service mysqld restart

Comment: and also when I look at /var/run/ there is nothing mysqld

Comment: @Fizzadar it looks for a socket because `localhost` tells that so, if you want to use tcp ip then you must change that to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install mysql server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

then create a database for your purposes:

```
mysql -u root -p --execute "create database DB_NAME; grant all on DB_NAME.* to DB_USER@localhost identified by 'DB_PASSWORD';"
```

then you should be fine.

I should point out that the confusion of mysql searching for a socket, even if specifying a port, is because mysql defaults to a socket when specifying `localhost` as an address, if you want to use tcp/ip then you should put an address like `127.0.0.1` there.

Answer (score 17):

Your HOST should change to '127.0.0.1', you must start service, especially if you are using xamp or lamp.

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
    'USER': 'DB_USER',
    'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',

} #Your HOST should change to '127.0.0.1', you must start service, especially if you are using xamp or lamp
```